# using third party smtp

Tags: php

I run a website that allows users to send email newsletters using their SMTP, not the host's SMTP. In that case the user can connect directly with his/smtp to send email. I am aware that some hosting companies do not allow this. Does anyone know the way around this? I need to move my website from the present host.

Comment: Have you considered a VPS? They're customisable enough to do what you need them to, but they're not as expensive as a dedicated server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SwiftMailer (http://swiftmailer.org/). The user would need to give you there login information, but then you can login to their email account and send the emails from their account. This will work all the time since the host can't tell if it's a standard mail client trying to send email. You can even send through a gmail account.

If that's not what you want, then you are probably referring to relaying, which you can just give up on. Open relay has been one of the biggest security holes on mail servers for over a decade. Nobody should have that issue anymore.

Comment: open relay isn't strictly a security hole. It was the norm before spammers came onto the scene.